# Error while using @microsoft/sp-dialog in SPFX TS1005

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, spfx, spfx-webparts, spfx-extensions

When using Dialog class from sp-dialog, gulp serve throws the error.

Created an SPFX project with react framework. installed sp-dialog with the following command.

```
npm install --save
```

in the .tsx file, I used the following lines of code.

```
import { Dialog } from '@microsoft/sp-dialog';

Dialog.alert('Hello world');
```

When use **gulp serve** or **gulp build**, the following error is thrown.

> Error - typescript -
>   node_modules@microsoft\sp-dialog\node_modules@microsoft\sp-core-library\lib\deferredClass\DeferredClass.d.ts(25,24):
>   error TS1005: ';' expected.

Comment: The error is throwing at the following line.  export default abstract class DeferredClass<Type, Instance> {

Comment: the abstract is causing the issue. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Late, I know, but there's a solution here: https://blog.mastykarz.nl/temporary-workaround-sharepoint-framework-dialogs/

Use

```
import { Dialog } from '@microsoft/sp-dialog/lib';
```

instead.